# View database user and password in PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

How do I change a user's password in Postgresql (using PgAdmin) so that I can connect with Rails to the Postgres database using these credentials?

So far: In PgAdmin I right clicked the database name, clicked Create Script and then typed the command:

`CREATE USER usr1 WITH PASSWORD 'pwd1!@#$';`

Question: where exactly in PgAdmin am I able to see the user and password or list of users and passwords? So far I am unable to see this in Db properties --> 'privileges'?? Any tips on other security elements? or something that can be improved in my current methods? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17):

In the file "pgpass.conf" in this path:

```
C:\Users\[User's name]\AppData\Roaming\postgresql
```

[image: Screenshot of Windows Explorer]

Comment: Anyone know the same for MAC?

Answer (score 12):

Login roles are common for all databases in a server. You can see them in the bottom of the object browser (left panel).
To execute arbitrary SQL query open Query tool (Ctrl-E) from Tools in main menu or click on icon with 'SQL' (previously you have to select a database).
To change user password execute SQL:

```
ALTER ROLE username PASSWORD 'newpassword'
```

`ALTER USER` is an alias for `ALTER ROLE`. Read about it in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-alterrole.html).

Comment: As my edit was rejected, I will leave this here as a comment. It is required to pass the `newpassword` within single quotes, e.g., `ALTER ROLE username PASSWORD 'newpassword'`. This is shown in the linked docs, but is not obvious in the answer itself.

Answer (score 12):

Run the query from pgadmin:

```sql
SELECT rolname, rolpassword FROM pg_authid;
```

This requires superuser privileges to protect the password.

Comment: And then find some sketchy website to crack the MD5 hashes?